# Interpolate on the fly to get previous valid entry from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

If I have an indexed `pandas.DataFrame` like this:

```
>>> Dxz = pandas.DataFrame({"x": [False,False,True], "z": [0,2,0], "p": [0.2,0.4,1]})
>>> Dxz.set_index(["x","z"], inplace=True)
>>> Dxz
           p
x     z     
False 0  0.4
      2  0.2
True  0  1.0
```

How do I get it to return me the value for `p` given a valid index tuple, and the value of the previous present index tuple if the index is not valid? For example, assuming it was a method “lookup_or_interpolate”, I'd like to see something like this:

```
>>> Dxz.lookup_or_interpolate((False, 0))["p"]
0.4
>>> Dxz.lookup_or_interpolate((False, 1))["p"]
0.4
>>> Dxz.lookup_or_interpolate((True, 23))["p"]
1.0
>>> Dxz
           p
x     z     
False 0  0.4
      2  0.2
True  0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `reindex`:

```
import pandas as pd
Dxz = pd.DataFrame({"x": [False,False,True], "z": [0,2,0], "p": [0.4,0.2,1]})
Dxz.set_index(["x","z"], inplace=True)
print Dxz.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(False, 0), (False, 1), (False, 100), (True, 23)]), method="ffill")
```

output:

```
             p
False 0    0.4
      1    0.4
      100  0.2
True  23   1.0
```